# Can SOLR map query terms one-to-one with matched terms?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, information-retrieval

I am currently working on a people search tool using SOLR to facilitate the indexing + fuzzy search across multiple fields (with edismax), using various filters such as SynonymFilterFactory, WordDelimiterFactory etc and disabling TF-IDF.

This works very well, except for a few cases where a search term is matched multiple times. For example, searching for "Martin XXXX" returns "Marvin Martin" as the highest result because it matches Martin against both "Marvin" and "Martin".

Matching a search term against multiple words in a document, in general, makes a lot of sense. However, in the case of people search, I'd like it to only add the maximum score for each search term (i.e., map each search term to only one word in the document (person's name / information)).

Is there a mechanism in SOLR/Lucene which would allow me to force a one-to-one mapping between search term and matched term?

You can see the issue below in the debug for the query:

```
    0.27641854 = (MATCH) sum of:
      0.27641854 = (MATCH) sum of:
        0.15077375 = (MATCH) weight(FullName:martin in 118169) [NoTFIDFSimilarityClass], result of:
          0.15077375 = score(doc=118169,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
    ), product of:
            0.15077375 = queryWeight, product of:
              1.0 = idf(docFreq=1619, maxDocs=328317)
              0.15077375 = queryNorm
            1.0 = fieldWeight in 118169, product of:
              1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
                1.0 = termFreq=1.0
              1.0 = idf(docFreq=1619, maxDocs=328317)
              1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=118169)
        0.12564479 = (MATCH) weight(FullName:marvin^0.8333333 in 118169) [NoTFIDFSimilarityClass], result of:
          0.12564479 = score(doc=118169,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
    ), product of:
            0.12564479 = queryWeight, product of:
              0.8333333 = boost
              1.0 = idf(docFreq=105, maxDocs=328317)
              0.15077375 = queryNorm
            1.0 = fieldWeight in 118169, product of:
              1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
                1.0 = termFreq=1.0
              1.0 = idf(docFreq=105, maxDocs=328317)
              1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=118169)
```

The query is e.g.,

```
 http://domain/solr/peoplefinder/select?q=Martin~&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&qf=FullName&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true&debug=true
```

Comment: Did you try using omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" in your field definition? Then the number of different matches will be ignored in the scoring.

Comment: This didn't change anything for me. In this case, it's not because it is matching the same word twice (i.e., one match, higher frequency), but because it is matching the same query term against one word exactly and another word via a fuzzy match. You can see this in debug, the frequency for both terms is 1.0.

Comment: So there shall only be a match, if all of the given words are found somewhere in the document?

Comment: @cheffe, no, the point is - if I search for "Martin" and there is someone called "Marvin Martin" then it should return the score for "Martin" but not "Marvin". That is, it should return the sum of the _maximum_ score for each _query term_, not simply the sum of all scores.

Comment: What you're asking for looks similar to ElasticSearch `multi_match` query with `best_fields` as a scoring strategy. ExtendedDisMax which you use is somewhat similar to the `multi_match`, but I guess, not 100% equal.

Comment: As I'm solving a similar task right now, not for human names, but other kind of highly structured data, I know that the first thing you should do is to clearly describe all use-cases, and especially corner cases, because the order of the matches for a particular query is highly dependent on personal tastes and other aspects opf the task.

Comment: Have you tried boosting exact matches? Something like `q=Martin^10%20Martin~`

Comment: @mschonaker, while this works in certain cases it doesn't solve the underlying problem. For example, I have a friend called "Martins Xxxs" who is often search for as "Martin Xxx". While I do not expect him to be the first match, I do not want Marvin Martin to appear as the first search result, since this is completely unintuitive to the user. We actually want fuzzy search to be allowed to be useful as there are plenty of mechanisms already for exact matches.

Comment: @user3159253 Such use cases are indeed exactly how we noticed this issue.

Comment: Well, I also thought so until discovered some glitches in my own task :). E.g. should frequency of a matched term be important to the scoring? How should partial matches (e.g. Marvin vs Marvell vs Martina) be scored. What if a name includes several terms (words), and more than one are matched to to the fuzzy single term query, should such matches have higher scores than matches with only one suitable term?

Comment: Isn't this (a SpanFirstQuery) what you need? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3925

Comment: Ah ha! Yes, that looks like it might do the trick. I will try it out and let you know :).

Comment: Did the SpanFirstQuery help?